# Export R package functions to parallel cluster within the R package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-package, rparallel

There are functions (like `function1`) within an R package I'm working on which rely on helper functions (like `h_function1` and `h_function2`) in my package. I'm parallelizing to repeatedly call `function1` within another function in my package.

Currently, in my package I'm using the code

```
parallel::clusterExport(cl, varlist=c("h_function1", "h_function2"), envir=environment())
parallel::parSapply(X=1:100, FUN=function1, cl=cl)
```

where `cl` is cluster from the parallel package that was passed into the function. This however assumes that the helper functions `h_function1` and `h_function2` are loaded from my package into the local environment, which may not be true for some users.

What is a way to flexibly export the functions to the cluster? Is it possible to export all functions of the package by package name?

Comment: If all these functions live in your package namespace, you don't (need to) assume that the user has loaded anything into "the local environment".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually do this with the following code:

```
parallel::clusterEvalQ({library("<package-name>")})
```